# Programmatically Creating Sub Domains

Tags: php, cakephp, dns, subdomain

I have this site where a user selects a template for his site. I have to create a sub domain for that user on my site which will apply the selected template. My question is can I create a subdomain programmatically if yes then how? I am using cakephp. I want that users site will be accessible on some url after selecting a template.

Comment: you need to setup a wildcard for dns. check out DNS for subdomains.

Comment: yup do it all the time, don't know cake, and you need to do it with a bash script not php, well you could but its just going to call some server functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, if you're running your own DNS servers, you can programmatically append new sub-domains to your DNS configuration files.  I would probably not recommend that.

What most sites (like Wordpress.com and what not) most likely do is setup their DNS to point `*.wordpress.com` to their web server, then programmatically see if the sub-domain matches a valid account, then respond accordingly.

Most DNS servers support wildcard domains, such as:

```
*.yoursite.com.   3600 IN  MX 10 host1.yoursite.com.
```

so consult your manuals or help files for whatever DNS service you're using.  Hope this helps!

Comment: To be a complete answer, this might need some input on how to incorporate with cake - likely within routes.php